# Saving a remote image with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, gd

Morning all,

Theres a few questions around this but none that really answer my question, as far as I ca understand. Basically I have a GD script that deals with resizing and caching images on our server, but I need to do the same with images stored on a remote server.

So, I'm wanting to save the image locally, then resize and display it as normal.

I've got this far...

```
        $file_name_array = explode('/', $filename);
        $file_name_array_r = array_reverse($file_name_array);  

        $save_to = 'system/cache/remote/'.$file_name_array_r[1].'-'.$file_name_array_r[0];

        $ch = curl_init($filename);
        $fp = fopen($save_to, "wb");

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        $options = array(CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,
                         CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                         CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                         CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60); // 1 minute timeout (should be enough)

        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
```

This creates the image file, but does not copy it accross? Am I missing the point?

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I sorted it! After examing my images rather than my code a little closer, it turned out some of the images were erroring on their side, rather than mine. Once I selected an image that worked, my code worked too!

Cheers as always though guys :)

Answer (score 3):

More simple, you can use the *file_put_contents* instead of *fwrite*:

```
$file_name_array = explode('/', $filename);
$file_name_array_r = array_reverse($file_name_array);  
$save_to = 'system/cache/remote/'.$file_name_array_r[1].'-'.$file_name_array_r[0];
file_put_contents($save_to, file_get_contents($filename));
```

or in just 2 lines :)

```
$file_name_array_r = array_reverse( explode('/', $filename) );  
file_put_contents('system/cache/remote/'.$file_name_array_r[1].'-'.$file_name_array_r[0], file_get_contents($filename));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply al3cs! Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately), I'm no longer working on that project, I'll still keep your solution in mind for next time though...

Answer (score 0):

Personally i don't like to use curl functions that write into a file. Try this instead:

```
    $file_name_array = explode('/', $filename);
    $file_name_array_r = array_reverse($file_name_array);  

    $save_to = 'system/cache/remote/'.$file_name_array_r[1].'-'.$file_name_array_r[0];

    $ch = curl_init($filename);
    $fp = fopen($save_to, "wb");

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    $options = array(CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
                     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
                     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true //Return transfer result
                     );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    //Get the result of the request and write it into the file
    $res=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fwrite($fp,$res);
    fclose($fp);
```

But you can use something more simple without curl:

```
$file_name_array = explode('/', $filename);
$file_name_array_r = array_reverse($file_name_array);  
$save_to = 'system/cache/remote/'.$file_name_array_r[1].'-'.$file_name_array_r[0];
$content=file_get_contents($filename); 
$fp = fopen($save_to, "wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I get an "Unsupported Request
PUT to http://imagepath.com/image.jpg not supported. Reference #8.9ea178d5.1274174788.863a82c" error. I have however sorted it, and it was me being a spanner....

Comment: Just a notice: you should have used `CURLOPT_FILE => $fp`, otherwise `fwrite($fp,$content);` doubles the memory consumption.